# How to get test coverage percentage for java maven based program?

Tags: java

I have a Java program based on maven and for that I need to know the test coverage percentage. For testing, I am using testng.

I can already run the tests using command mvn test. All the tests are passing and I can see the report in surefire-reports/index.html. But I could not get the test coverage percentage that I need to supply for reporting.

```
mvn test
```

Expected result is Test Coverage Percentage is x%

Comment: In Intellij you can right-click on root test folder and select run `all tests with coverage`, you will get full report.

Comment: Jacoco is what you're looking for. Read through the docs
https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/

Comment: @LudovDmitrii I was able to run all tests using Run with Coverage -> All Tests <TestNg> but still did not see any coverage numbers anywhere.

Comment: It has to be in a top bar `View -> Tool Windows -> Coverage`. If it's not, then something wrong with your IDE.

Comment: Thanks @LudovDmitrii I got the coverage numbers. Please feel free to post it as answer and I will accept it then. One more thing, can you please tell me which test coverage report plugin does intellij use by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intellij to get a coverage report. Right-click on a test folder: run all with coverage and here you go,

[image: how to run all tests with coverage]

maybe you will need to call report window explicitly, it's located View -> Tool Windows -> Coverage. The last question about default plugin. The only information I can tell you about it is located in settings-> plugins: [image: coverage plugin location]

Answer (score 1):

For those Using **Netbeans** IDE, do the following

1. Right Click on the Project
2. Select Code Coverage
3. then choose Show Report

As shown Below

[image]

Code coverage for every file will be displayed.